# ValueError: Cannot assign "'auth.User'": "Token.user"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token

i am getting error while i generating token with user id. it's showing me error **ValueError: Cannot assign "'auth.User'": "Token.user"  must be a "User" instance.**
it would be great if anyone could figure me out where should i make changes in my code. thankyou so much in advance.

views.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class Product_CategoryCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    # token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    token = Token.objects.create(user=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    print(token.key)
    model = Product_Category
    queryset = Product_Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Product_CategoryAdd_Serializer
```

Comment: Why you don't use `django-rest-auth`? It gives you a lot of endpoints like `login`, `logout` e.c. out of box and it works with tokens.

Answer (score 3):

you should pass an instance of the user

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 

user = get_user_model().objects.first()
token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
```

If you've already created some users, you can generate tokens for all existing users like this:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

see [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

Comment: it's showing , AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'first'

Comment: try get_user_model().objects.first()

Answer (score 0):

The Error says it must be a User Instance
means you should pass an object of User model

**Error Logic** :

you are currently passing **User model's name** to the **Token**

```
   token = Token.objects.create(user=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

**settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL** will return the User model's name but not its instance, it is of type string,you can see its type using

```
print(type(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL))
```

**Output**: 
`<class 'str'>`